# Getting the error "The name 'ObjectPoolingManager' does not exist in the current context"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, object-pooling

I am following a [tutorial](https://gamedevacademy.org/unity-fps-shooting-tutorial/) on how to make a gun to shoot a bullet, but I am getting this error:

> "The name 'ObjectPoolingManager' does not exist in the current
> context"

I am following the tutorial exactly as is, and I don't know why this happens.

Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PL : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject bulletPrefab;

    public Camera playerCamera;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            GameObject bulletObject = ObjectPoolingManager.Instance.GetBullet(true);
            bulletObject.transform.position = playerCamera.transform.position + playerCamera.transform.forward;
            bulletObject.transform.forward = playerCamera.transform.forward;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, have you implemented such a type? Because it's not Unity built-in ;)

Comment: Seems to be one of their objects, according to Google. Tutorial probably missing something you need.

Comment: @Nikki9696 that is most likely the issue

Comment: @Nikki9696 I believe you are correct, i read the entire tutorial, i believe the `ObjectPoolingManager` class was excluded from the tutorial. @Arya Akhavein [Heres a tutorial](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/introduction-to-object-pooling#5ff8d015edbc2a002063971b) to make your own `ObjectPoolingManager` since they didn't included it with the project.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't worry too much about object pooling until you're comfortable with the basics of Unity and C#. It is an optimization pattern. I would just `GameObject.Instantiate(yourBulletPrefab)` and `GameObject.Destroy(yourBulletGameobject)` instead until performance becomes an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Unity doesn't have built-in object pooling. You have to create yourself. Tutorial which you followed forgot to add it.